# mvc pass input values to controller parameters

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, button

First of all, I'm new to web development, so forgive me for this newbie question.

I have 4 inputs on my View, which I would like to send to my controller when a button is pressed.

```
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="text" name="description" />
<input type="text" name="link" />
<input type="date" name="date" />
```

And here is my ControllerMethod:

```
public ActionResult AddNewsToList(string title ="a", string description = "b", string link = "c", string pubDate = "01-02-2016")
    {
        Models.RssWriter.createNewsItem(title, description, link, pubDate);

        return View("News", NewsFeed.Models.RssReader.GetRssFeed());
    }
```

So can anyone guide me to making a button that can do this for me? Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**

This is how it actually looks like right now:

*CreateNews.cshtml*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewsToList"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Titel
            </th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" />
            </td>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Beskrivelse
            </th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="description" />
            </td>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Link
            </th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="link" />
            </td>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Udgivelsesdato
            </th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="date" name="date" />
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="AddNewsToList" name="AddNewsToList" value="Tilføj" />

}
```

But this does not seem to work.

Comment: I don't see why this post deserves at negative vote. It is hard to find a similar question on this site. Every question about submitting forms is more advanced, like have two buttons at the same time.

Comment: what have you tried? do you know anything about HTML, <form> tag? Also why do you have default parameter values defined for your action?

Comment: The default values are because they are optional

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"?

Comment: Do you have your ActionResult decorated with [HttpPost] ?

Comment: @GendoIkari Hm, you're right. I'll delete my suggestions. Ziv is probably onto something.

Comment: @Leonard Your comment was right, I only needed to specify the Controller in BeginForm. Thank you!

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen haha, okay! I guess I'll create an answer, then! :)

Comment: @Leonard you can link to here in your answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.Object%29. It appears that if you provide the action name, you must also provide the controller name. Otherwise the parameter is interpreted as a RouteValues object. He can probably just use BeginForm() without any parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to specify the controller name as the second argument to the `BeginForm` method.

As @Gendolkari also pointed out: *"it appears that if you provide the action name, you must also provide the controller name. Otherwise the parameter is interpreted as a RouteValues object. He can probably just use BeginForm() without any parameters."*

Compare:

- `BeginForm(String, Object)`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.Object%29
- `BeginForm(String, String)`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29